# Definition of convergence of a sequence to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is a question from the *Understanding Analysis* book:

> Informally speaking, the sequence $\sqrt{n}$ "converges to infinity".
>   Imitate the logical structure of Definition 2.2.3 to create a rigorous
>   definition for the mathematical statement $\lim x_n = \infty$. Use
>   this definition to prove $\lim \sqrt{n} = \infty$.

Definition 2.2.3:

> A sequence $(a_n)$ *converges* to a real number $a$
>   if, for every positive number $\epsilon$, there exists an $N \in
>  \mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n \geq N$ it follows that $|a_n - a| <
>  \epsilon$.

I don't know what it means for a definition to be "rigorous". Would the following definition suffice?

A sequence $(a_n)$ "converges to infinity" if, for every positive number $\epsilon$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n \geq N$, it follows that $a_n > \epsilon$.

Not really sure if the above definition would work though. Would appreciate help if it's not a rigorous definition.

Comment: Yes, your definition is correct

Comment: And it is rigorous, although it is more common to use something besides $\epsilon$, like $a_n > M$ for all positive $M$. We tend to think of $\epsilon$ as being a small quantity, but this is just a style thing; what you've written is completely correct and rigorous.

Comment: @TonyS.F. : As in the unbounded sequence definition? I thought the notions of convergence to $\infty$ and unboundedness could have subtle differences that I didn't know of.

Comment: Yes there is a subtle difference, an unbounded sequence is one in which $\forall M>0, \exists k$ such that $x_k > M$. No matter how big you make $M$, I can always find a term in the sequence, $x_k$, which is bigger than $M$. However, to "converge" to infinity we require something stronger. In what you've written we not only find a term $x_n$ which is bigger than $M$ but we actually find a point in the sequence, say $N$, where ALL the terms past $N$ are bigger than $M$: $\forall n\geq N, x_n >M$. The sequence $a_n = 0$ for even $n$ and $a_n=n$ for odd $n$ is unbounded but doesn't go to infinity